# Run the array multiple times

Tags: php, sql

Right now my script connects to an api and sends an sms, 1 number at a time.  I want it to pull from a local sql db then repeat the response for each number in the db.

```
$data['post'] = array (
    '_rnr_se'     => $rnrse,
    'phoneNumber' => '1234567890', 
    'text'        => 'This is a test SMS!',
    'id'          => '' 
);

// Send the SMS
$response = xcurl::fetch('api.phonegateway.com/', $data);

// Evaluate the response
$value = json_decode($response['data']);
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You have to setup a local database, fetch the numbers from this database, and then execute above code for each number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy from the [docs](http://at.php.net/mysql_fetch_array)

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data['post'] = array ( '_rnr_se' => $row['number'], 'phoneNumber' => $row['phone_number'], 'text' => $row['text'], 'id' => '' );

// Send the SMS $response = xcurl::fetch('api.phonegateway.com/', $data);

// Evaluate the response $value = json_decode($response['data']);` 
}
```

Comment: that was fast, so this will go thru all the numbers in my db and send the response to each?

Comment: When you adapt the code accoridngly, yes. Inside the while loop, every code you write will be as often executed as results are returned from the database.

Comment: thx again but i ran into a problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130885/excute-an-array-with-while-statement