# Excute an array with while statement

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Ok i am tryna make this code excute for every phone number in my db. Before following advice here i was only able to send to one number at a time, i got advice to add a while statment to loop it. However my code don't wanna work no more. Here is before and after. I know i did something wrong.

**BEFORE (Working-no db)**

```
// Set SMS options
$data['post'] = array (
  '_rnr_se'     => $rnrse,
  'phoneNumber' => '123456789', 
  'text'        => 'This is a test SMS',
  'id'          => ''
);

// Send the SMS
$response = xcurl::fetch('api.gateway.com/', $data);

// Evaluate the response
$value = json_decode($response['data']);

if($value->ok) {
  echo "SMS message sent! ({$data['post']['phoneNumber']}: {$data['post']['text']})";    
} else {
  echo "Unable to send SMS! Error Code ({$value->data->code})\n\n";
  echo     'data: '; print_r(    $data); echo "\n\n";
  echo 'response: '; print_r($response);
}
```

**AFTER(Not working with db)**

```
// Set SMS options
mysql_connect("localhost", "music", "") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error()); mysql_select_db("music");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, numbers FROM account_templates");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $data['post'] = array (
    '_rnr_se'     => $rnrse,
    'phoneNumber' => $row['numbers'], 
    'text'        => 'This is a test SMS',
    'id'          => '' 
  );

  // Send the SMS
  $response = xcurl::fetch('api.gateway.com', $data);

  // Evaluate the response
  $value = json_decode($response['data']);
}
if($value->ok) {
  echo "SMS message sent! ({$data['post']['phoneNumber']}: {$data['post']['text']})";
} else {
  echo "Unable to send SMS! Error Code ({$value->data->code})\n\n";
  echo     'data: '; print_r(    $data); echo "\n\n";
  echo 'response: '; print_r($response);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run the array mutiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130598/run-the-array-mutiple-times)

Comment: not really its a different problem, same script

Comment: try to fix it up the best i can, hope someone can help me!

Comment: There is a code button in the editor (the one with the ones and zeros).

Comment: thx to who ever fixed it

Comment: it not sending correctly, i dnt think it putting the number, i also try the foreach method and only was sending to the first number

Answer (score 0):

The way it is now, the sending process is running through the while loop, but the process of checking whether the SMS was sent is not.

It could be as simple as changing the position of a `}`.

Take away this bracket:

```
 // Evaluate the response
  $value = json_decode($response['data']);
} <------------------------------------------------ remove that one
```

and move it

```
     echo 'response: '; print_r($response);
   }
 } <------------------------------------------------add here
```

Comment: THANKS, do you have any idea how i can see and debug what is being posted, i know it posting correctly but i think i made a mistake with my sql.

Comment: @Pekka do you see any reason y i get No database selected

Comment: @Aaron you need to select one after connecting: http://www.php.net/mysql_select_db

Comment: @Pekka hate to keep bothering you, but do yu have any idea y it juss workin for the first number in the db?

Comment: @Aaron nope, sorry. If you moved the bracket as I wrote above, the loop should run through. Try checking `mysql_num_rows()` to see how many rows your query returns.